# Dot product for lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to implement a dot product between two lists of numbers using only functions from the Prelude library. I've written the following function:

```
dot :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> a
dot x y = sum $ zipWith (*) x y
```

that I tested as follows:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let n = 10^6
        x = (replicate n 2.0) :: [Double]
        y = (replicate n 3.0) :: [Double]
    print $ dot x y
    return ()
```

Unfortunately, this code leads to a stack space overflow for lists with 1 million of elements (using ghc 7.6.3 and optimization flag -O2).

For such a simple case, I would have expected ghc to be able to perform the necessary optimizations to avoid the cost of the recursive calls. Am I missing something? Is my implementation wrong?

Comment: How are the lists produced? This works for me with a simple `repeat 1.0`.

Comment: The issue here would be with how you are producing the arguments you are passing to `dot`. `dot` itself uses constant space.

Comment: Which of the three functions is implemented with recursive calls?

Comment: @Alec That doesn't jive with my tests. Are you sure that comment applies to GHC 7.6.3?

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm ashamed to say I checked back only to 7.8.4 (that's the oldest I have installed). Sorry for the confusion OP! That said, do consider upgrading to a more recent GHC version if you can! :)

Comment: I just upgraded my GHC compiler to version 7.10.3 and it works just fine (no more stack overflow).

Answer (score 7):

`sum` is (used to be) implemented with `foldr`. That's a bit of a dumb choice for *most* instances of `Num`; a strict left fold is better. Use

```
import Data.List

sum' :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum' = foldl' (+) 0
```

instead and your stack overflow will disappear.

Comment: I tested `sum` as well, and it was working fine, even for larger lists with 10^8 elements. I guess the problem was coming from the implementation of `zipWith`. Anyway, I just upgraded my GHC to version 7.10.3 and there's no more stack overflow using the standard versions of `sum` and `zipWith`